# Magento API Stopped Working After Domain Name Change

Tags: api, magento, soap

I had Magento SOAP API working perfectly until the client said Doh! We need it on this url instead, after I moved it it to that new url API will not run no matter what, I've made all the necessary url changes in the API script, Configuration, the DB and the site files.

Is there somewhere the old url may be encoded where I'm not finding it using a find and replace?

For instance, I created a full cPanel back up of the site, restored it to another server, whet back through and changed all the instances of the new url back to the old url in the db, site files and configuration and WHALA! SOAP starts working again..

Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear cache? Does the magento admin/frontend work (can you log in)?

Comment: "after I moved it it to that new url API will not run no matter what" could use a little fleshing out.  How are you using the API, what happens when you try to run it, what error/behaviors do you get when you do run it?

Comment: Yes, everything but the API works. I am using it to display products from a certain category on a page outside the install. For now I'm just going to use an include to the Mage.php and  Mage::getResourceModel to show the data, it seems to be faster than the API was. If anyone wants the code, let me know and I'll post it.